Trouble with OkHttpClient JAVA
Having trouble OkHttpClien, my code looks correct still receiving invalid request by server.. Im missing anything here ? ( Invalid request.) in tomcat.. anyone can help me? chatgpt says its everything ok.. any tip to debbug or to make this code work would be good thank you very much !
        public void postAsync(String payload, String action, Callback callback) throws JSONException {
        //Gson gJSON = new Gson();
        // Convert payload to a JSON object
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

        // Add the action property to the JSON object
        jsonObject.put("action", action);
        jsonObject.put("payload",payload);

        // Convert the modified JSON object back to a string
        String payloadWithAction = jsonObject.toString();

        RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(payloadWithAction, MediaType.parse("application/json"));

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .url("https://moveroute.org/php/run-register-api.php")
                .post(body)
                .build();
        System.out.println(request.isHttps());
        client.newCall(request).enqueue(callback);

    }

try {
            makeLogin.postAsync(payload, "login", new Callback() {
               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                   // Handle failure
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               @Override
               public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {

                   if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                       String jsonResponse = response.body().string();
                       Gson gJson = new Gson();
                       CRUD.Response responseJSON = gJson.fromJson(jsonResponse, CRUD.Response.class);
                        System.out.println(responseJSON.getMessage().toString());
                       if (responseJSON.getStatus()){
                        Intent goToMainView = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainView.class);
                        startActivity(goToMainView);
                        finish();
                       }






                   } else {
                       // Handle unsuccessful response
                   }
               }
           });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }


When you copy-paste the request to a browser, do you get a valid response?

I don't see any HTTP headers defined. Are you sure the request works without authentication, cookies or other site specific headers?

Solved the problem, it was a problem with the hosting.. Thank you guys
